# Python tempfile with a context manager on Windows 10 leads to PermissionError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, temporary-files, file-writing

**OS:** Windows 10

**Python:** 3.6 (Anaconda)

I am trying to use a simple temporary file with a context manager to write a simple csv.

```
import csv
import tempfile

fp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
with open(fp.name,'w',newline='') as f:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f)
    csv_out.writerow(['first_name','last_name'])
    csv_out.writerow(['foo','bar'])
```

Running this results in this permission error:

```
with open(fp.name,'w',newline='') as f:
E       PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\TEMP\\tmp2bqke7f6'
```

Changing the Windows permission status on the temp directory `C:\TEMP\` to allow full access by all users does not help.

[Per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied) I tried running my Windows cmd as Admin, still did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212435/permission-denied-to-write-to-my-temporary-file

Comment: @CDuvert I think they are very similar but the link above deals with a NamedTemporaryFile. Mine addresses the TemporaryFile. It is good to have both for reference.  See here for details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: Python 3.9: `with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for a similar problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212435/permission-denied-to-write-to-my-temporary-file)), I found (and tested) a solution which works for your problem as well.

You just need to add a `delete=False` argument in your `fp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()` line.

It seems that the file actually gets created in that line, and then trying to open it and write in it a second time (`with open(fp.name)...`) forbids you do to so.

Comment: Strangely this works.  Looks like its related to this bug: https://github.com/bravoserver/bravo/issues/111

Answer (score 0):

[`tempfile.TemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) already returns a [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), so here's how to use it:

```py
with tempfile.TemporaryFile('w') as f:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f)
    csv_out.writerow(['first_name', 'last_name'])
    csv_out.writerow(['foo', 'bar'])
    # do things with the temporary csv file
    ...
```