# Can't figure out why PyDub is not working

Tags: python, pydub, audiosegment

I'm trying to use pydub for a music project, but when trying to play sounds with this chunk of code

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("s1.wav")
play(sound)
```

i get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:184: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vicen/Desktop/music project/mian.py", line 6, in <module>
    play(s1)
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 74, in play
    _play_with_ffplay(audio_segment)
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 18, in _play_with_ffplay
    seg.export(f.name, "wav")
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 809, in export
    out_f, _ = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(out_f, 'wb+')
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\vicen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpvwotqts5.wav'
```

Does someone understand why it isn't working? I am fairly new to python so i don't.

Answer (score 0):

The python script encountered a `Permission Error`
It is trying to read `'C:\\Users\\vicen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpvwotqts5.wav'`
file but doesn't have permission to write in the directory.

Changing permissions on the above mentioned Temp folder should solve the problem.

Or you could run your python script using `sudo` command. Since you are using windows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652720/how-to-run-sudo-command-in-windows#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20sudo%20command,choosing%20%22run%20as%20administrator.%22) should help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Fix [from here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/209#issuecomment-502427261):

```
pip install simpleaudio
```

Pydub uses [tempfiles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) extensively .As suggested [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/209#issuecomment-325681959) you can add `TMPDIR` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the tempfile , as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58955530/15203736)
so the file ***playback.py*** , which is one of the files of this pydub module (you may find it at Python\Python-version-\Lib\site-packages\pydub ) , must be modified.
there are two recommended methods to solve this,

1. mentioned [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/209#issuecomment-602260075)
2. create a custom tempfile like below at ***playback.py***

`

```
import subprocess
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from .utils import get_player_name, make_chunks
import random
import os
import tempfile


class CustomNamedTemporaryFile:
    """
    This custom implementation is needed because of the following limitation of tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile:

    > Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open,
    > varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later).
    """
    def __init__(self, mode='wb', delete=True, suffix = ''):
        self._mode = mode
        self._delete = delete
        self.suffix = suffix

    def __enter__(self):
        # Generate a random temporary file name
        file_name = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), os.urandom(24).hex())
        # Ensure the file is created
        open(file_name+self.suffix, "x").close()
        # Open the file in the given mode
        self._tempFile = open(file_name+self.suffix, self._mode)
        return self._tempFile

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._tempFile.close()
        if self._delete:
            os.remove(self._tempFile.name)
            
def _play_with_ffplay(seg):
    PLAYER = get_player_name()
    # with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
    with CustomNamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb', suffix = ".wav") as f:
        seg.export(f.name, "wav")
        subprocess.call([PLAYER, "-nodisp", "-autoexit", "-hide_banner", f.name])
```

'