# How to export large audio files with pydub python?

Tags: python, audio, out-of-memory, pydub, audiosegment

I'm trying to export an audio file with **pydub**. I did it in a `mp3` format, however it was really slow. Then I found out that using a `wav` format can make the process faster, but the size of the output file will be bigger.

```
audio.export("C:/Users/me/audio.wav", format="wav")
```

I am using a **64 bit version** of python, so pydub can export 1 hour long audio files. But I need to export **10 hours long** audio file. Here it says "MemoryError".

How can i make pydub export a 10 hours long audio file?
Or maybe there are some **alternatives** to pydub that will let you export a 10 hours long audio file?

Edit:

The problem isn't in export. The problem is in `AudioSegment`. When I try to open a new large file (10 hours long audio), a **'MemoryError'** appears.

```
audio = AudioSegment.from_wav('C:/Users/me/audio.wav')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think it's currently not possible to create a 10 hour audio file in wav format because of this issue [Add Support for large audio files ( > 2GB) · Issue #135 · jiaaro/pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/135 "Add Support for large audio files ( &gt; 2GB) · Issue #135 · jiaaro/pydub"). One hour of uncompressed audio at 16bit, Stereo, 44100 Hz takes 635 MB, see [Audio File Size Calculator](https://www.colincrawley.com/audio-file-size-calculator/ "Audio File Size Calculator").

Comment: Maybe this question can help you though https://stackoverflow.com/q/66398978/2932052

Comment: Maybe there is a way to create a large audio file not in a wav format? But I want it to export not so slowly as mp3.

Comment: The question linked to in my last comment seems to have an answer concerning this

Comment: @Wolf sorry I can't understand where is the answer to my question. I believe it is in a github post (link in a Ajay's answer) but can you please explain it for me

Comment: it's the hint to install `simpleaudio`

Comment: @Wolf ok, thank you. I’ll try this

Comment: @Wolf I installed simpleaudio but it doesn't seem to help. Do I need to do something else (for example import it) to make it work. Also I edited a question. The problem isn't in export. It is in AudioSegment. It throws an error when I make this variable too big (when the input file is large).

Comment: What actually are you trying to do (programmatically)? Could it maybe be done with an existing tool like audacity?

Comment: BTW: WAV will only allow 6.8 hours: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Limitations

Comment: The already mentioned Audacity has no size limit for recording: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/recording_length.html - so I guess you can also work on large files, see for example https://www.audacityteam.org/about/features/editing/ and https://www.audacityteam.org/about/features/effects/

Comment: @Wolf ok, thank you