# Extracting frame fails with: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have the following method to create a dummy video file:

```
def create_dummy_mp4_video() -> None:
    cmd = (
        f"ffmpeg -y "  # rewrite if exists
        f"-f lavfi -i color=size=100x100:rate=10:color=black "  # blank video
        f"-f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 "  # silent audio
        f"-t 1 "  # video duration, seconds
        "output.mp4"  # file name
    )
    proc = subprocess.run(
        shlex.split(cmd),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False,
    )

    if proc.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception()


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class FakeVideo:
    body: bytes
    width: int
    height: int
    fps: int
    size: int
    frames: int
    length_s: int


def video() -> FakeVideo:
    w, h, fps, sec, filename = 100, 100, 10, 1, "output.mp4"
    create_dummy_mp4_video()
    video_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
    with open(video_path, "rb") as file:
        body = file.read()
        size = len(body)
        frames = fps // sec
        return FakeVideo(
            body=body, width=w, height=h, fps=fps,
            size=size, frames=frames, length_s=sec,
        )
```

then I want to extract a frame at specific time, I did it like this:

```
async def run_shell_command(frame_millisecond, data: bytes) -> bytes:
    async with aiofiles.tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("wb") as file:
        await file.write(data)
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            "ffmpeg",
            "-i",
            file.name,
            "-ss",
            f"{frame_millisecond}ms",  # seek the position to the specific millisecond
            "-vframes", "1",  # only handle one video frame
            "-c:v", "png",  # select the output encoder
            "-f", "image2pipe", "-",  # force output file to stdout,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
        level = logging.DEBUG if proc.returncode == 0 else logging.WARN
        LOGGER.log(level, f"[cmd exited with {proc.returncode}]")
        if stderr:
            print(level, f"[stderr]{stderr.decode()}")
            LOGGER.log(level, f"[stderr]{stderr.decode()}")
        return stdout


async def runner():
    v = video()
    time = int(v.length_s / 2 * 1000)
    res = await run_shell_command(time, v.body)
    assert isinstance(res, bytes)
    assert imghdr.what(h=res, file=None) == "png"


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(runner())
```

This code fails whit the following error:

```
/tmp/tmpzo786lfg: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Please help to find the problem with my code.
During investigation I found that it works if I change the size of the video like that:

```
f"-f lavfi -i color=size=1280x720:rate=25:color=black "  # blank video
```

but I want to be able to process any video.

I use ffmpg 4.3.3-0+deb11u1

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables. Maybe if you have frames `1280x720` and you try to save as `100x100` then it creates wrong file - and you may have to manually resize frame before saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to make sure the data is written to the temporary file, before executing FFmpeg.

I don't have any experience with `asyncio` and `aiofiles` and I am running Windows 10, so I am not sure about the Linux behavior...

I tried to add `await file.flush()` after `file.write(data)`, but the FFmpeg execution result was "`Permission denied`".

I solved it using the solution from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768241/4926757):

- Add `delete=False` argument to `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`:

  ```
   async with aiofiles.tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("wb", delete=False) as file:
  ```
- Add `await file.close()` after `await file.write(data)`.
  Closing the file is used for making sure that all the data is written to the file, before executing FFmpeg.
- Add `os.unlink(file.name)` before `return stdout`.

---

Complete code:

```
import subprocess
import asyncio
from dataclasses import dataclass
import shlex
import aiofiles
import os
import logging
import imghdr

def create_dummy_mp4_video() -> None:
    cmd = (
        f"ffmpeg -y "  # rewrite if exists
        f"-f lavfi -i color=size=100x100:rate=10:color=black "  # blank video
        f"-f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 "  # silent audio
        f"-t 1 "  # video duration, seconds
        "output.mp4"  # file name
    )
    proc = subprocess.run(
        shlex.split(cmd),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, #stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False,
    )

    if proc.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception()


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class FakeVideo:
    body: bytes
    width: int
    height: int
    fps: int
    size: int
    frames: int
    length_s: int


def video() -> FakeVideo:
    w, h, fps, sec, filename = 100, 100, 10, 1, "output.mp4"
    create_dummy_mp4_video()
    video_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
    with open(video_path, "rb") as file:
        body = file.read()
        size = len(body)
        frames = fps // sec
        return FakeVideo(
            body=body, width=w, height=h, fps=fps,
            size=size, frames=frames, length_s=sec,
        )



async def run_shell_command(frame_millisecond, data: bytes) -> bytes:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212435/permission-denied-to-write-to-my-temporary-file/23212515
    async with aiofiles.tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("wb", delete=False) as file:
        await file.write(data)
        #await file.flush()  # Flush data to file before executing FFmpeg ?
        await file.close()  # Close the file before executing FFmpeg.
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            "ffmpeg",
            "-i",
            file.name,
            "-ss",
            f"{frame_millisecond}ms",  # seek the position to the specific millisecond
            "-vframes", "1",  # only handle one video frame
            "-c:v", "png",  # select the output encoder
            "-f", "image2pipe", "-",  # force output file to stdout,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
        )

        stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
        level = logging.DEBUG if proc.returncode == 0 else logging.WARN
        #LOGGER.log(level, f"[cmd exited with {proc.returncode}]")
        if stderr:
            print(level, f"[stderr]{stderr.decode()}")
            #LOGGER.log(level, f"[stderr]{stderr.decode()}")

        os.unlink(file.name)  # Unlink is required because delete=False was used

        return stdout


async def runner():
    v = video()
    time = int(v.length_s / 2 * 1000)
    res = await run_shell_command(time, v.body)
    assert isinstance(res, bytes)
    assert imghdr.what(h=res, file=None) == "png"


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(runner())
```

---

Notes:

- I removed the `LOGGER` because I couldn't find the LOGGER module.
- Next time, please add all the imports to your posted code (it's not so trivial finding them).