# Printing to NamedTemporaryFile on Windows

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, subprocess, temporary-files

**The original Problem - MCVE**

The following script should use chrome headless, to print to pdf (I am running windows 10, and python 3.6):

```
import subprocess
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

output = NamedTemporaryFile()
CHROME_PATH=r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome"'

chrome_args=[CHROME_PATH,
             '--headless',
             r'--print-to-pdf="{}"'.format(output.name),
             '--disable-gpu',
             'https://www.google.com/',]

subprocess.call(chrome_args,shell=True)
```

However the generated file, is just empty.

**Attempt at debugging**

To try and figure out what is going, on I adapted the script to the following:

```
import subprocess
CHROME_PATH=r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome"'

chrome_args=[CHROME_PATH,
             '--headless',
             r'--print-to-pdf="c:\Users\timmc\Documents\output.pdf"',
             '--disable-gpu',
             'https://www.google.com/',]

print(r" ".join(chrome_args))  #For debuging

subprocess.call(chrome_args,shell=True)
```

In this case, there is just no file generated at the expected location. The result of the print is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" --headless --print-to-pdf="c:\Users\timmc\Documents\output.pdf" --disable-gpu https://www.google.com/
```

if I run the following (creating a raw string literal), everything works as expected and the file is produced.

```
subprocess.call(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" --headless --print-to-pdf="c:\Users\timmc\Documents\output.pdf" --disable-gpu https://www.google.com/', shell=True)
```

Having searched around on stack-overflow, and tried a few things, I still can’t get the original script to work. Any ideas?

Part of the problem is that I can't seem to get any meaningful debug from the subprocess call. Any help with that would also be much appreciated.

Comment: can you try `'--print-to-pdf',output.name` (2 separate arguments, no quotes)

Comment: also try without `shell=True`

Comment: That seems to give just the same result as before, the script runs, but the file is empty.

Comment: removing shell=True, gives the following error: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Comment: don't wrap the chrome exe into quotes: `CHROME_PATH=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome'` let subprocess handle it. and remove `shell=True` and use 2 args. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Again, same as before. I included the quotes, because when I tried running the command in command prompt, I had problems because of the spaces in 'Program Files'

Comment: don't put quotes. joining spaces to your args is not representative of the way python runs your program. Make it simple. see my answer.

Comment: Any other thoughts on this, its driving me insane

Comment: why don't you use the command line which works and inject the filename inside using ``str.format`. I've edited & undeleted my answer. That _should_ work even if it's not the best solution.

Comment: ah, good idea. I'll try that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the reason the subprocess wasn't running properly, is that when python creates a NamedTemporaryFile in windows, it does so with a FILE_SHARE_DELETE tag which prevents any other process accessing it unless it also has this tag. There is more discussion of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169101/how-to-create-a-temporary-file-that-can-be-read-by-a-subprocess).

Fortunately, Django comes with its own [NamedTemporaryFile](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NamedTemporaryFile) which was made to partially address this problem, and does so well enough for these purposes.

Comment: I _never_ use this temporary file feature because I already ran into problems. Now I know why :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer instead of commenting again and again, but obviously I cannot test this.

The issue is mainly the forcing of the double quotes & `shell=True`. Leaving the quoting to `subprocess` (also in `CHROME_PATH`) and splitting arguments properly usually work. I've solved a lot of questions here with this technique.

Since your comments state that it does not, and that you found a workaround, let me suggest an improvement of this workaround: injecting the output filename in the command line that works:

```
subprocess.call(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" --headless --print-to-pdf="{}" --disable-gpu https://www.google.com/'.format(output.name), shell=True)
```

not satisfactory to me but it has a good chance to work.

Comment: I'm still getting empty files, running this script. Is there anyway I can get any kind of error messages that might be returned from subprocess.call()?

Comment: change to ``check_output`. This is becoming "interesting"

Comment: That gives the following: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome', '--headless', '--print-to-pdf', 'C:\\Users\\timmc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp761ozhvy', '--disable-gpu', 'https://www.google.com/']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: I finally figured out why it wasn't working, solution below if you are interested.