# tempfile.mkstemp permissions settings

Tags: python, file-permissions, mkstemp

I am using `tempfile.mkstemp` to generate a random available filename and write some content with `os.fdopen`. I then pass the filename to a task via `celery`.

This task opens the file, processes the content, and finally removes the file.
In testing this works fine, however I have realised that this will break in my live environment where the user running the task is not the same as the one which creates the file.

This means that the user cannot open the file because `tempfile.mkstemp` sets the permissions to `600`(`-rw-------`).

I cannot make both processes run by the same user, so is there some way to modify the file permissions set by `tempfile.mkstemp`?

I am running Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I would encourage you to [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) first when you have a question. Then, come to StackOverflow.

Comment: @robobrobro I appreciate your point, but I did read that documentation, and I couldn't see anything explicitly stated regarding the file permissions

Comment: "The file is readable and writable only by the creating user ID. If the platform uses permission bits to indicate whether a file is executable, the file is executable by no one."

Comment: Ah fair enough. Although I don't think it's clear whether that can be altered? Looks like the only way may be `os.chmod`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you use os.fdopen after you call mkstemp(), you may be better off using tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False). It returns a Python file object instead of an `fd`.

Either way, the returned file will have mode=0600, so you will need to change it. Use `os.fchmod(temp_file.fileno(), 0640)` or similar (change the mode as per your needs).

Comment: I'm accepting this as you've clarified the `os.chmod` issue for me

Answer (score 3):

No, apart from manually modyfing permissions using `chmod` command, there is no way to modify permissions of file created by `tempfile.mkstemp`. This function by design creates temporary file *in the most secure manner possible* so *the file is readable and writable only by the creating user ID*. See [mkstemp documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp).

Create your temporary file using [`tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) or [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) instead.

Comment: Ok, I thought this may be the case, do you think it is better to use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` or to use `os.fchmod` on the `mkstemp` file?

Comment: I would use `NamedTemporaryFile`. Looking at your use case you actually don't  need *secure* temporary file. So there's no point in using `tempfile.mkstemp`

Comment: NamedTemporaryFile is as secure as tempfile.mkstemp - they use the same code internally. Call NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) to get the mkstemp() behavior, plus a python file object (which you need anyway).

Comment: It does seems as though `NamedTemporaryFile` also creates files with the `0600` permissions mode

Comment: You're right. All three `mkstemp`, `TemporaryFile`, and `NamedTemporaryFile` use actually the same internal function for creating files. And `006` mode is hardcoded there. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541760/can-i-set-the-umask-for-tempfile-namedtemporaryfile-in-python) you can find some workarround